# ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

Tags: python

I modified my code but another error appeared:

```
    fin=open("ah_d_01_CGATGT_L003_R1_001.fastq","r")
    fout=open("ah_d_01_CGATGT_L003_R1_001.filt.fastq","w")
    maxN=4
    contatutte=containcl=0
    seq=("")
    for line in fin:
         seq +=fin.read()
         ctrl=fin.read()
         qual=fin.read()
         countN=seq.count("N" ,0, len(seq))
        if maxN>countN:
           fout.write(line) # +"\n"
           fout.write(seq)
           fout.write(ctrl)
           fout.write(qual)
           containcl+=1
   fin.close
   fout.close
   print contatutte,containcl
```

Error:

```
  File "filtraN.py", line 7, in <module>
    seq +=fin.read()
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

Comment: Because you're mixing iteration (`for line in fin`) and read (`fin.read()`) methods, which is **exactly what the error message tells you**. Pick one or the other! There are dozens of **Related** questions in the sidebar `----->`

Answer (score 0):

try this code and enjoy...
read details from here - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

```
fout=open("ah_d_01_CGATGT_L003_R1_001.filt.fastq","w")
maxN=1000
contatutte=containcl=0
seq=""

with open('ah_d_01_CGATGT_L003_R1_001.fastq') as f:
    for line in f:
        seq += line
        ctrl = line
        qual = line
        countN = seq.count("N", 0, len(seq))
        if maxN>countN:
            #fout.write(line)  #eventualmente aggiungi +"\n"
            fout.write(seq)
            fout.write(ctrl)
            fout.write(qual)
            containcl+=1

        if 'str' in line:
            break

fout.close
print contatutte,containcl
```